# jquery each loop call function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use an array of functions ins in a jquery each loop and pass parameters to sad functions.

Something like what is below.

```
var test = function(x) { return x+1;};
var test2 = function (x) { return x+2};
var mark = [test,test2]; 

mark.each(function() { $(this)(3)});
```

> expected result 
>  4
>  5

how do I achieve this.

Working example of answer

```
var test = function(x) { return x+1;};
var test2 = function (x) { return x+2;};
var mark = [test,test2]; $.each(mark, function () {
  console.log(  this(3));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `this(3)`

```
$.each(mark, function () {
    this(3);
});
```

also note, you need `$.each` to iterate and array not `mark.each` as `.each` is available only on jQuery object.

Comment: @Archer it works for me. I have updated my question to reflect it

Comment: How bizarre.  I did it in the console on this page and it returned the functions as object references.  When I did it in jsfiddle it worked.  Oh well!  +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

you would need to put your array as the first parameter of your **$.each()** method

there are **2 different types** of jQuery **each()** methods

the first iterates over both **objects** and **arrays**:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
// array
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
   alert( index + ": " + value );
});

// object
var obj = {
      "flammable": "inflammable",
      "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
      alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

the second iterates over a **collection of elements**

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

selector each look like this

```
// collection of elements
$("li").each(function( index ) {
     console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```